# MySQL Partitioning based on ID and Week

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `acme`.`partitioned_table` (
  `id` INT NULL,
  `client_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `create_datetime` INT NOT NULL,
  `some_val` VARCHAR(45) NULL);
```

I'd like to partition this table in such a way that each client’s data is stored in its own partition based on the *client_id* AND each partition can only contain data for 1 week based on the *create_datetime*. This is done so we can drop weekly one week’s worth of data based each client’s own retention policy.

For example, some clients would like to have 3 months of data while others may have longer data retention policies.

I am having a hard time being new to MySQL to come up with a proper partitioning strategy. How can I partition by Week based on the INT column.  To throw a curve ball this might be hosted on AWS RDS later.

**Many thanks in advance,**

M

Comment: Rather than implementing a complex partitionning scheme, why not just run `delete` statements to purge client's history?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: 1) Have a requirement for separate storage. 2) Deletes produce redo logs and slow database down. It is much more efficient to drop a partition.

Answer (score 0):

Your clients x weeks level of partitioning would lead to a lot of partitions.  This implies a lot of disk space and queries will be slower.

Your requirement for "separate storage" would be better handled by either separate tables or separate databases.

If you also need to do queries across all clients, we need to discuss things further.

One of the "guidelines" for partitioning is not to partition a table with less than a million rows.

If a client's table is big enough to justify partitioning, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint for more discussion.  If not big enough, then either simply do the `DELETE`, or see this for more options:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig .

There are a lot of `DATETIME` functions that are messy if you use `INT`:

```
`create_datetime` INT
```

Comment: Sincerely appreciate your taking a look. I never have to query across partitions. Disk space is not an issue. The volume of data definitely justifies the partitioning. Separate tables and or databases are not the option. Still my question remains unanswered :-( Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be asking for `SUBPARTITIONing`.  There are several limitations in such, but check it out.